# Mysql LIKE or by closest match

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM store WHERE 
concat_ws(name, type, location) LIKE :search1 OR :search2 OR :search3

for($n=0; $n<$count; $n++)
   $query->bindValue(':search'.$n, '%'.$search[$n].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);}
}
```

I have a search query, i break user's input into array, ex:array('i', 'love', 'apple');

my question is how to ORDER by the closest match?

it search 3 columns, so if user type new york apple, it will return many content with new york from location column, and many content are nothing to do with apple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this, you will need Full Text Search(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). Which is a bit more complicated than LIKE, but certainly quicker and smarter.

Comment: I have try fulltext search before, because my db will have many chinese, and i have did some testing, MATCH AGAINST have trouble to search some chinese's content

Comment: To be able to add words or other indexed terms in such languages to a FULLTEXT index, you must preprocess them so that they are separated by some arbitrary delimiter such as “"”. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

Comment: That since there (as far as I know), are no characters showing the end of a word, you have to add them to let full text search work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without full text search (where the default values wouldn't work anyway for your query because "i" wouldn't be treated as a word):

```
order by ((concat_ws(name, type, location) LIKE :search1) +
          (concat_ws(name, type, location) LIKE :search2) +
          (concat_ws(name, type, location) LIKE :search3)
         ) desc
```

This orders by the most matches to the fewest.  Your `where` clause needs to follow the same format as well, with three different `like` clauses.